# create table in SparK SQL

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

i would like to create table in spark sql i am using scala ide i've added dependencies from maven
I tried this and it gave me the error below

```
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}
import org.apache.spark.sql._

object HiveFromSpark {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("HiveFromSpark").setMaster("local")
    val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)
    val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
  
    sqlContext.sql("SET hive.metastore.warehouse.dir=hdfs://localhost:9000/user/hive/warehouse")
    sqlContext.sql("CREATE TABLE Test (code string,description string,code string) ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' STORED AS TextFile")
    sqlContext.sql("LOAD DATA INPATH 'C:\\Users\\mhattabi\\Desktop\\cars.csv' OVERWRITE INTO TABLE Test")
    val df = sqlContext.sql("SELECT * from Test")
    df.show()
  }
}
```

I got this error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: [1.1] failure: ``insert'' expected but identifier CREATE found
>
> CREATE TABLE Test (code string,description string,code string) ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' STORED AS TextFile

Comment: In the `CREATE TABLE` query, you are using the same identifier "code" twice: `(code string,description string,code string)` I would try with another name

Comment: I've already change it , and still got the same issue.Thanks in advance

Comment: Mmmm, can you execute the `CREATE TABLE` command directly in the spark shell?

Comment: yes it is possible but it is not possible through the scala IDE thanks